# Binary XML file line #17 : Error inflating class com.camerakit.CameraKitView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera

i get this error when i run android app i using camera kit for display my camera frontend phone this error is visible sometime.

Images

Error :

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDAxU.png)

Xml :

[xml file line 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B8VA.png)

Version Camera Kit :

[Version i using for camera kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr8mC.png)

Comment: I believe it should be: `app:permissions="camera"`

Comment: @Andy not working